# reciprocal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I don't understand some of the terminology in this  question. I googled reciprocal vectors and got an article on reciprocal lattices, but I'm not sure if that is what they are talking about in this question. Also, when they say that ${\bf A}$, ${\bf B}$, and ${\bf C}$ are defined by ... plus cyclic permutations, again I looked at the wikipedia article on the subject, but I still do not understand the concept. Does anyone have a link for a clear explanation?

> The vectors ${\bf a}$, ${\bf b}$, and ${\bf c}$ are non-coplanar, and
>   form a non-orthogonal vector base. The vectors ${\bf A}$, ${\bf B}$,
>   and ${\bf C}$, defined by
>
> $$ {\bf A} = \frac{{\bf b}\times {\bf c}}{{\bf a}\cdot{\bf b}\times
>  {\bf c}}, $$
>
> plus cyclic permutations, are said to be reciprocal vectors. Show that
>
> $$ {\bf a} = \frac{{\bf B}\times {\bf C}}{{\bf A}\cdot{\bf B}\times {\bf
>  C}}, $$
>
> plus cyclic permutations.

thanks

Comment: Reciprocal vector: the vector which has the same direction as that of vector $A$ but has magnitude reciprocal to that of vector $A$, is called the reciprocal of vector $A$ and is denoted as vector $A^{-1}$

Comment: @shadabAli This is totally wrong. And no mathematician would *ever* write $A^{-1}$ unless $A$ is a nonsingular (square) matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cyclic means a cyclic permutation of the operands:
$$
{\bf A} \to {\bf B}, {\bf B} \to {\bf C}, {\bf C} \to {\bf A} 
\quad 
a \to b, b \to c, c \to a
$$
This gives
$$ 
{\bf A} = \frac{{\bf b}\times {\bf c}}{{\bf a}\cdot({\bf b}\times {\bf c})}
\quad
{\bf B} = \frac{{\bf c}\times {\bf a}}{{\bf b}\cdot({\bf c}\times {\bf a})}
\quad
{\bf C} = \frac{{\bf a}\times {\bf b}}{{\bf c}\cdot({\bf a}\times {\bf b})} 
$$
and 
$$ 
{\bf a} = \frac{{\bf B}\times {\bf C}}{{\bf A}\cdot({\bf B}\times {\bf C})}
\quad
{\bf b} = \frac{{\bf C}\times {\bf A}}{{\bf B}\cdot({\bf C}\times {\bf A})}
\quad
{\bf c} = \frac{{\bf A}\times {\bf B}}{{\bf C}\cdot({\bf A}\times {\bf B})}
$$

From [Reciprocal Lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_lattice#Mathematical_description)

> [..] the "crystallographer's" definition, comes
>   from defining the reciprocal lattice to be $e^{2 \pi
>  i\mathbf{K}\cdot\mathbf{R}}=1$ which changes the definitions of
>   the reciprocal lattice vectors to be
>
> $ \mathbf{b_{1}}=\frac{\mathbf{a_{2}} \times
>  \mathbf{a_{3}}}{\mathbf{a_{1}} \cdot (\mathbf{a_{2}} \times
>  \mathbf{a_{3}})}$ and so on for the other vectors.  The
>   crystallographer's definition has the advantage that the definition of
>   $\mathbf{b_{1}}$ is just the reciprocal magnitude of
>   $\mathbf{a_{1}}$ in the direction of $\mathbf{a_{2}}
>  \times \mathbf{a_{3}}$, dropping the factor of $2
>  \pi$.

Checking the magnitude:

$$ 
\lVert{\bf A}\rVert = \frac{\lVert {\bf b} \times{\bf c}\rVert}{\lVert{\bf a}\rVert\lVert{\bf b}\times {\bf c}\rVert\cos\angle({\bf a}, {\bf b} \times{\bf c})}
=
\frac{1}{\lVert{\bf a}\rVert ({\bf e_a} \cdot {\bf e}_{{\bf b} \times{\bf c}})} 
$$

**Solving the question:**

Using the "bac-cab" rule 
${\bf a}\times({\bf b}\times{\bf c}) = {\bf b}({\bf a}\cdot {\bf c}) - {\bf c}({\bf a}\cdot {\bf b})$ we go for the nominator of ${\bf B}\times{\bf C}$:
$$
({\bf c}\times {\bf a})\times({\bf a}\times{\bf b}) =
{\bf a}(({\bf c}\times{\bf a})\cdot{\bf b})-{\bf b}(({\bf c}\times{\bf a})\cdot{\bf a})=
{\bf a}(({\bf c}\times{\bf a})\cdot{\bf b})
$$
because ${\bf c}\times{\bf a} \perp {\bf a}$.
This gives
$$
{\bf B}\times{\bf C} 
= 
\frac{{\bf a}(({\bf c}\times{\bf a})\cdot{\bf b})}{({\bf b}\cdot({\bf c}\times {\bf a}))({\bf c}\cdot({\bf a}\times {\bf b}))}
= 
\frac{{\bf a}}{{\bf c}\cdot({\bf a}\times {\bf b})} \\
{\bf A}\cdot({\bf B}\times{\bf C})
=
\frac{{\bf b}\times {\bf c}}{{\bf a}\cdot({\bf b}\times {\bf c})}
\cdot
\frac{{\bf a}}{{\bf c}\cdot({\bf a}\times {\bf b})}
=
\frac{1}{{\bf c}\cdot({\bf a}\times {\bf b})}
$$
Dividing those gives the desired result
$$
\frac{{\bf B}\times{\bf C}}{{\bf A}\cdot({\bf B}\times{\bf C})}
=
\frac{{\bf c}\cdot({\bf a}\times {\bf b})\,{\bf a}}{{\bf c}\cdot({\bf a}\times {\bf b})}
= {\bf a}
$$

Comment: hey thanks,
do you mean to say that we can use the magnitude to show the proof?
I'm a little stumped by this one, even now that I understand the terminology. do you have any suggestions on how to approach the solution?

Comment: The last bit above was to understand the last sentence of the cited text. Which proof and solution do you mean?

Comment: that the question is asking for, to show from

$$
{\bf A} = \frac{{\bf b}\times {\bf c}}{{\bf a}\cdot{\bf b}\times
 {\bf c}}
$$

that

$$
{\bf a} = \frac{{\bf B}\times {\bf C}}{{\bf A}\cdot{\bf B}\times
 {\bf C}}
$$

Comment: I added that bit.

Comment: It's worth noting that a . b x c = b . c x a = c . a x b is, as they are each the volume of the parallepiped whose sides are a, b, and c.

Answer (score 4):

I think they intended to write $A\cdot (B\times C)$, which is a scalar; the vectors are  non-coplanar, hence this scalar is nonzero and hence we can safely divide by this scalar.

[This wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) would be a good start.

Comment: oh I see, so then permutations would be, for example
$$ {\bf B} = \frac{{\bf c}\times {\bf a}}{{\bf b}\cdot{\bf c}\times {\bf
 a}}, $$
but I'm still not sure what they mean by reciprocal vectors...

Comment: @seanread It's just a name. Looking at ${\bf A} = \frac{{\bf b}\times {\bf c}}{{\bf a}\cdot{\bf b}\times
 {\bf c}},$, if you "cancel" $\bf b\times \bf c$, then you are left with $\bf A=\frac{1}{\bf a}$, the "reciprocal" of $\bf a$. Of course, you can't legitimately carry out this cancellation but it does help to explain the name.

Comment: @KimJongUn I've just asked [How much like reciprocals are reciprocal vectors? Is there a matrix division that allows $\mathbf{A} = 1 / \mathbf{a}$ in three or two dimensions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3828372/284619)