# How much like reciprocals are reciprocal vectors? Is there a matrix division that allows $\mathbf{A} = 1 / \mathbf{a}$ in three or two dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

A quote within the question [reciprocal vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1223719/284619) reads:

> $$ {\bf A} = \frac{{\bf b}\times {\bf c}}{{\bf a}\cdot{\bf b}\times
>  {\bf c}}, $$
>
> plus cyclic permutations, are said to be reciprocal vectors.

To the OP's comment

> ...but I'm still not sure what they mean by reciprocal vectors

found under [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1223723/284619), and interesting reply by<sup>†</sup> [@KimJongUn](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223719/reciprocal-vectors#comment2489190_1223723) says:

> It's just a name. Looking at ${\bf A} = \frac{{\bf b}\times {\bf c}}{{\bf a}\cdot{\bf b}\times  {\bf c}},$, if you "cancel" $\bf b\times \bf c$, then you are left with $\bf A=\frac{1}{\bf a}$, the "reciprocal" of . Of course, you can't legitimately carry out this cancellation but it does help to explain the name.

**Question:** How much like reciprocals are reciprocal vectors? Is there a matrix division that allows $\mathbf{A} = 1 / \mathbf{a}$ in three or two dimensions?

I think we can write it like that at least for 1D, but I'm not sure if there are issues with the sign.

---

<sup>†</sup>okay maybe it's not them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reciprocal vectors are defined if the three given vectors are linearly independent, because otherwise $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}=0$ (and also for all permutations). If the three vectors are linearly independent, then $\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}$ is orthogonal to both $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$, so it cannot be orthogonal also to $\mathbf{a}$.

If we take the three coordinate vectors $\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}$, the first of the reciprocal vectors is
$$
\dfrac{\mathbf{j}\times\mathbf{k}}{\mathbf{i}\cdot\mathbf{j}\times\mathbf{k}}=\mathbf{i}
$$
and similarly you get $\mathbf{j}$ and $\mathbf{k}$ for the other two.

More generally, if you take the scalar products of the first reciprocal vector with the vectors $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}$ you get
$$
\frac{\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}}{\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}}\cdot\mathbf{a}=1,
\quad
\frac{\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}}{\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}}\cdot\mathbf{b}=0,
\quad
\frac{\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}}{\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}}\cdot\mathbf{c}=0
$$
and similarly for the cyclic permutations. So the set of reciprocal vectors is nothing else than the dual basis with respect to the identification of the dual space with $\mathbb{R}^3$ itself by means of the scalar product.

Comment: Thanks, while I'd initially hoped for an answer of the form "and it turns out surprisingly that we can indeed divide one by $\mathbf{a}$ and get $\mathbf{A}$ I didn't think it would be forthcoming.

Comment: @uhoh No, you cannot define a division in a three dimensional algebra. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784166/why-are-there-no-triernions-3-dimensional-analogue-of-complex-numbers-quate/1784336#1784336

Comment: okay, I'd mentioned one, two and three dimensions individually.

Comment: @uhoh The cross product only exists for three-dimensional spaces. Before asking about inverses, you need to specify what multiplication you have in mind.

Comment: Yes. For 2D I'd always inserted a dummy unit vector in the third dimension thinking I'd go back and rewrite it for 2D explicitly later, and then never did. This is a good time for me to revisit that. Thanks!

Comment: to understand further I've just asked [Calculate reciprocal vectors of a two dimensional lattice without borrowing from the third dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3838557/284619) I reference this answer, if I've got it wrong please feel free to comment or edit there. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 2):

The operation $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ has the property that when you perform it twice (on real numbers) you get back $x$, and when performed on the number $1$, leaves it invariant (which also happens to be true for $-1$). "Negation" is another such operation (which leaves $0$ invariant, instead of $1$).

The source of the operation in the "reciprocal vectors" question has developed an operation on *triples of independent vectors in 3-space* with the property that when performed twice, brings you back to the same triple-of-independent-vectors. In that sense, it's a little bit analogous to the $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ operation on the real line. And if you regard the standard basis as a particularly nice triple of vectors (because when you stack them up into a $3 \times 3$ matrix, you get the identity), this operation has the property that it leaves invariant this 'special' triple. (I believe that it leaves invariant any positively-oriented orthonormal basis, but I could be wrong --- I didn't look all that closely.)

Note that this is an operation on *triples* of vectors. If you have a single vector $a$, but lack $b$ and $c$, you can't even define $A$. So it's certainly not very strongly analogous to reciprocals of single numbers in the real number line.

One last point: there are situations in which you have lists of non-zero numbers, and it makes sense to invert each one of them. This essentially never comes up in linear algebra, so it doesn't get a name there, but it comes up in some applications where we have lists of numbers, so it appears in some programming languages. In matlab, for instance, if `a` is a list of (nonzero) numbers, then `1 ./ a` is the list whose $i$th element is the reciprocal of the $i$th element of `a`. When might this be useful? Suppose that the $i$th element indicates the number of cars (uniformly randomly) crossing a "measuring point" on road $i$ in each hour. Then the $i$th element of the reciprocal indicates the expected waiting time for a car on road $i$, in hours.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer! While I use reciprocal vectors regularly in [this field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705547/284619) of physics research, I'm not a mathematician so it will take me some time to understand this fully. But I appreciate now that the operation is on n-tuples of vectors, and I've mentioned n=1, 2, and 3 in the question.

Comment: I had written something about how this resembled dual bases, and possibly Grassmann algebra, but deleted it because I wasn't at all certain. My guess, seeing this lattice-theory stuff, is that it's exactly something to do with dual bases.

Comment: I meant "when I was originally writing my answer, I put in a paragraph mentioning dual bases, but then deleted it before submitting the answer," All it said what "this might have something to do with dual bases or Grassmann algebra", as I recall. :(

Comment: ya when I saw "dual bases" in the other answer I just figured that out as well :-)